# Fixing the action back to an account page in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp.net mvc4 application, in which i have to logout from an account :

```
 if (_fonction == "User")
            {
                if (_is_admin == true) return RedirectToAction("Index");
                else
                {
                    Session["user"] = _u;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                }
            }
```

in the controller `User`

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["user"] == null) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
         return View(Session["user"]);
        }
```

the action `Logout`

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            if (_is_admin) { Session["user"] = null; return RedirectToRoute("Administration"); }
            else { Session["user"] = null; return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
        }
```

i do this : i log in to a user account then i disconnect so i'am in the home page , then i click into the `back` button of the browser i got the page of the account. When i refresh i returned to the home page. i think that the problem is in the `cache` and i don't think that make it null is a good idea .

So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: what is your expected behavior? when you do a logout, then press back, and refresh, the page should still be in the User Account view?

Comment: when i logout and i press back the page should still the home page not a user account because i'am not connected !!

Comment: the browser caches your pages. it doesn't matter if the user goes back to you user account view if he hits back. what matters is that **the user should not be able to do any web request (POST/GET/PUT/DELETE) on that view.** which is easily handled by `AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: so you suggest to add `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` or to use `AuthorizeAttribute`, what is the best way?

Comment: just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` as an attribute to your `User` controller's `Index` action to force non-cached results.

But I would strongly suggest to just use [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) because this will prevent unauthorized web requests done on a specific view. The benefit of using this is that you still give the users the liberty to cache your views and be secured at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to clean your cache then below is the javascript which helps you to hard refresh your page on click of the browser back button

```
if (window.name != "") { // will be '' if page not prev loaded            
            window.name = ""; // reset to prevent infinite loop
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
window.name = new Date().getTime();
```

put the above **"javascript"** code on your page. so, it will hard refresh your page.